# Why is pmap [heap] readings different from the actual program's heap memory usage?

Tags: c, linux, pmap

I was learning how `pmap` analyzes the memory usage of a program. Running this very basic program that initializes an `int` array with **1,000,000** elements should theoretically use **4,000,000 bytes** (I tried adding or removing `stdlib.h`, but I got the same memory readings):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() {
    int h[1000000];
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
        h[i] = i;
    }
    while(1) {

    }
}
```

This is the `pmap -x` result (the program is called **fixedmemory**):

```
10356: ./fixedmemory
Address            Kbytes     PSS   Dirty    Swap  Mode  Mapping
0000000000400000     504     148       0       0 r-x--  fixedmemory
000000000048d000      16      12       8       0 r----  fixedmemory
0000000000491000      12      12      12       0 rw---  fixedmemory
0000000000494000      20       8       8       0 rw---    [anon]
000000002dd7d000     136       8       8       0 rw---    [heap]
000000739e568000       4       0       0       0 r----    [vvar]
000000739e569000       4       0       0       0 r-x--    [vdso]
0000007fc14ef000    3912    3912    3912       0 rw---    [stack]
----------------  ------  ------  ------  ------
total               4608    4100    3948       0
```

Looking at the PSS results because they are supposed to be more accurate[<sup>[1]</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proportional_set_size#:%7E:text=In%20computing%2C%20proportional%20set%20size,is%20reported%20as%20the%20PSS.), I noticed that the stack memory usage was **3912**. Supposing that the metric uses **Kibibytes (KiB)**, the results are accurate and off by around **0.1472%**, which is marginal.

If I then try to allocate memory using `malloc` using this program:

```
#include <stdlib.h>  
int main() {
    int* s = malloc(1000000*4); 
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
        s[i] = i;
    }
    while(1) {

    }
    free(s);
}
```

These are the results that I get:

```
18296: ./fixedmemory
Address            Kbytes     PSS   Dirty    Swap  Mode  Mapping
0000000000400000     504       4       0       0 r-x--  fixedmemory
000000000048d000      16       8       8       0 r----  fixedmemory
0000000000491000      12      12      12       0 rw---  fixedmemory
0000000000494000      20       8       8       0 rw---    [anon]
000000000f2e8000     136       8       8       0 rw---    [heap]
000000708fd6a000    3908    3908    3908       0 rw---    [anon]
000000709013b000       4       0       0       0 r----    [vvar]
000000709013c000       4       0       0       0 r-x--    [vdso]
0000007fdacbd000     132      12      12       0 rw---    [stack]
----------------  ------  ------  ------  ------
total               4736    3960    3956       0
```

Why is the heap reporting **8** **KiB** even though the heap memory usage should, theoretically, be equal to **4,000,000** bytes or **3906.25** **KiB**? I noticed that there is a memory mapping called `[anon]` that reports an almost exact theoretical value of 3908 KiB. Is this the actual memory used by `malloc`, or am I missing something? If it is, then why is it called `[anon]`? And If I were to benchmark a C program's memory usage, would `[anon]`'s reading be always equal to the heap's memory usage of the program?

Comment: What OS?  What compiler?  What compiler options?  And read this:  https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Malloc-Tunable-Parameters.html